# ¿como puedo hacer que tres cadenas de texto se unan?

Tags: javascript, html

He estado intentando unir tres cuadros de texto diferentes para una tarea, pero al momento de querer unir los tres cuadros de texto en solo uno, no lo he logrado hacer, alguna idea...?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ejemplo de JavaScript</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>


<form name="prueba">
   Primera Frase: <input type="text"id="textA"; />
   Frase final: <input type="text"id="textB"; />
<br>
<br>
   Contenido Medio
<br>
    
   <textarea name="textC" id="textC" cols="50" rows="10">
   </textarea>
<br>
</form>

<script>
var c1=document.getElementById('textA').textContent;
var c2=document.getElementById('textB').textContent;
var t1=document.getElementById('textC').textContent;

</script>
<form name="resultado">
Resultado: 
<br>
<button onclick="document.write(+c1+t1+c2)" id="Boton">Unir</button>
<br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cree un pequeño código con tu fuente, espero te sirva:

```js
function unirTexto(){

var c1=document.getElementById('textA').value;
var c2=document.getElementById('textB').value;
var t1=document.getElementById('textC').value;
var resultado= document.getElementById('resultado');
resultado.innerHTML = c1+c2+t1;

}
```

```html
<form name="prueba">
   Primera Frase: <input type="text"id="textA"; />
   Frase final: <input type="text"id="textB"; />
<br>
<br>
   Contenido Medio
<br>
    
   <textarea name="textC" id="textC" cols="50" rows="10">
   </textarea>
<br>
</form>


Resultado: <span id="resultado"></span>
<br>
<button onclick="unirTexto()" id="Boton">Unir</button>
```

Comment: gracias, realmente estaba atorado con esto

Comment: a su orden, para eso estamos

Answer (score 0):

Si se trata de un input o de textarea hay que utilizar el valor `value`no el textContent.

```js
Boton.addEventListener("click", function(){

var c1=document.getElementById('textA').value;
var c2=document.getElementById('textB').value;
var t1=document.getElementById('textC').value;
Resultado.innerHTML += c1+c2+t1;
  
})
```

```css
#Resultado{color:red;}
```

```html
<form name="prueba">
   Primera Frase: <input type="text"id="textA"; />
   Frase final: <input type="text"id="textB"; />
<br>
<br>
   Contenido Medio
<br>
    
   <textarea name="textC" id="textC" cols="50" rows="10">
   </textarea>
<br>
</form>

<script>

</script>

<p id="Resultado">Resultado: </p> 
<br>
<button id="Boton">Unir</button>
```